# How can I replace the apps in the SGSII's stock launcher dock?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, launcher

When I turn on my Galaxy S2, on the very bottom, there are the default icons for "phone", "email", "web", and "applications". On the Galaxy Tab (running Android 3.2), if I want to free up any of those apps and replace them with my own, I simply press and hold like any other app and just delete and replace with my own.

On the Galaxy SII Skyrocket (running 2.3 Gingerbread), I press and hold and nothing happens. Is there a way for me to change the shortcuts in the dock on the SGSII, similar to the way I can on the Galaxy Tab?

Comment: Try to keep your questions to one question a piece, or at least several extremely related question. I will say, though, that Honeycomb was only released for tablets. There are no phones that have or will receive an update to Honeycomb.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Ice Cream Sandwich update, pretty much all you have to do is hit the Menu button from the home screen, select Edit, and then long press the application you want to change.

For Gingerbread, click the Applications icon, then follow the same procedure (Menu button, edit, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternative launcher like Launcher Pro / ADW / Zeam / Go Launcher etc.

They allow you to customize the icons that you want at the bottom of the screen in addition to many, many more useful features.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the Applications icon, then bring up the menu and there should be edit in there. You will now be able to drag icons back and forth, remember to press the menu button again to save it.